# Initialize PostgreSQL Container with docker-entrypoint-initdb.d script

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL 11.5 docker container.  In doing so, I want to run a SQL script that creates the necessary users, tables, etc.  However, whenever the container starts I see the following error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start


WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
****************************************************
WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
         This will allow anyone with access to the
         Postgres port to access your database. In
         Docker's default configuration, this is
         effectively any other container on the same
         system.

         Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
         it in "docker run".
****************************************************
waiting for server to start....2019-09-16 17:16:26.568 UTC [42] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-09-16 17:16:26.677 UTC [43] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-16 17:16:25 UTC
2019-09-16 17:16:26.691 UTC [42] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql: Permission denied
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:11.5

ADD ./scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

And, my `init.sql` file looks like this:

```
CREATE USER mydb WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO mydb;
```

You'll notice neither of them does anything terribly complicated.  However, I'm still getting the `permission denied` error.  I've connected to the running container and confirmed that the init.sql file is in place on the filesystem.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: how you run the container? docker run command?

Comment: @Adiii I've tried running the docker command, as well as using docker-compose as shown in one of the submitted answers. Either way, I still get the error.

Comment: I posted the answer please check

Comment: So the issue with file permission you can check the updated answer'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So from this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/9d8e2448436b2af1ea715822c2d209d493760007/11/Dockerfile) I assume the user is postgress.

Try with this Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:11.5
USER postgres
RUN whoami
ADD ./scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

**update:**

Seems like the file not owned by Postgres user.

Try to set permission

```
ADD ./scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chown postgres:postgres /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Comment: Yes.  No change.

Comment: are you running the file `docker exec -it`?

Comment: like this `docker run -it --rm abc bash -c "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"`?

Comment: I've tried starting it using docker-compose, as well as docker build/docker run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199538/discussion-between-adiii-and-shadowman).

Answer (score 10):

### Initialize Postgres container with Data

Create a `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgress-postgresql:
    image: postgres:11.3
    volumes:
    #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/postgress/postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgress
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Create a `init.sql` with the script

```
CREATE USER platops WITH PASSWORD 'platops';
CREATE DATABASE platopsdb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE platopsdb TO platops;
```

RUN with `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: After seing your comment i have cleaned up every volume and tried with the same it is working fine. I am updating the init.sql

Comment: I copied & pasted your code verbatim and still received the same error.  I'm running Docker 19.03.2 and Docker-compose 1.24.1

Comment: How to hide this 'platops' password in a docker-secret?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/

Comment: Using "./directory" instead of just "directory" solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, mounted a .sh file via docker volumes. I checked permissions via `ls -lah`, in my case it was just `-rw-r-----`.

Using `chmod 644 filename` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The underlaying problem in our case was that the sql script was stored on a ntfs partition mounted with ntfs-3g which by default has got permissions' functionality disabled (https://superuser.com/questions/451475/chmod-doesnt-work). Running it on a normal ext4 partition solved the problem.